# Given an increasing polynomial, how do you efficiently find x values for fixed intervals of y?

Tags: algorithm, math

**Problem:** Given a polynomial of degree *n* (with coefficients *a*<sub>0</sub> through *a*<sub>n-1</sub>) that is guaranteed to be increasing from *x* = 0 to *x*<sub>max</sub>, what is the most efficient algorithm to find the first *m* points with equally-spaced *y* values (i.e. *y*<sub>i</sub> - *y*<sub>i-1</sub> == *c*, for all *i*)?

**Example:** If I want the spacing to be *c* = 1, and my polynomial is `f(x) = x^2`, then the first three points would be at *y*=1 (*x*=1), *y*=2 (*x*~=1.4142), and *y*=3 (*x*~=1.7321).

---

I'm not sure if it will be significant, but my specific problem involves the *cube* of a polynomial with given coefficients.  My intuition tells me that the most efficient solution should be the same, but I'm not sure.

I'm encountering this working through the problems in the ACM's [problem set](http://home.a-eskwadraat.nl/~kink/icpc2012.pdf) for the 2012 World Finals (problem B), so this is mostly because I'm curious.

---

**Edit:** I'm not sure if this should go on the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This belongs here more than at Math SE. On Math SE you will just get answers telling you to solve the equations for x, given your y values. Here, someone might be able to help you do this programatically or come up with a better solution.

Comment: any particular programming language you are working with?

Comment: I prefer Python for fun things like this, simply because you don't have to deal with boilerplate and lower-level stuff as much.  I'd accept a solution in any language, though, or even a general push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an X for a given Y using a binary search. It's logarithmic time complexity, proportional to the size of the range of x values, divided by your error tolerance.

```
def solveForX(polyFunc, minX, maxX, y, epsilon):
    midX = (minX + maxX) / 2.0
    if abs(polyFunc(midX) - y) < epsilon:
        return midX
    if polyFunc(midX) > y:
        return solveForX(polyFunc, minX, midX, y, epsilon)
    else:
        return solveForX(polyFunc, midX, maxX, y, epsilon)

print solveForX(lambda x: x*x, 0, 100, 2, 0.01)
```

output:

```
1.416015625
```

Edit: to expand on an idea in the comments, if you know you will be searching for multiple X values, it's possible to narrow down the [minX, maxX] search range.

```
def solveForManyXs(polyFunc, minX, maxX, ys, epsilon):
    if len(ys) == 0:
        return []
    midIdx = len(ys) / 2
    midY = ys[midIdx]
    midX = solveForX(polyFunc, minX, maxX, midY, epsilon)
    lowYs = ys[:midIdx]
    highYs = ys[midIdx+1:]
    return solveForManyXs(polyFunc, minX, midX, lowYs, epsilon) + \
    [midX] + \
    solveForManyXs(polyFunc, midX, maxX, highYs, epsilon)

ys = [1, 2, 3]
print solveForManyXs(lambda x: x*x, 0, 100, ys, 0.01)
```

output:

```
[1.0000884532928467, 1.41448974609375, 1.7318960977718234]
```

Comment: I had been thinking something along those lines would be good, but I wondered: Is the fastest way to find the first *m* values simply to repeat this *m* times?  This definitely works when you're looking for a single value, but for the general case it seems like there is redundant effort.

Comment: One quick optimization that comes to mind is, if you're looking for N values of X, then plug in the (N/2)th Y value first. Then use X(N/2) as your maxX for each Y value under N/2, and as your minX for each Y value above N/2.